# How to find an instances of a test by status from across all builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-api

I'm creating an api request using the Jenkins api. Im struggling to make the link from the build api docs, to the testreport api docs. So far I have:

api/json?&pretty=true&tree=allBuilds[TestResultAction[*]]]

This isn't working, I think TestResultAction should be something else to get to the TestReport, but it dosen't seem to be TestReport either. 
Can someone help me with the query so I can find instances of a test and whether or not it passed across all builds?